# I can't figure out this step in one of my uni tutorials. It seems the equations has been rearranged incorrectly

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a section of a tutorial question I received in hydraulics:
[image]

I managed to find the question online and it agrees with the answer I have been provided with (not sure if I'm allowed to share links??).
The answer I get however is d=1.168m.  When I've googled the equation all the calculators agree with me, but I feel like I'm missing something as the image I've provided is from a text book.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally spoke to my lecturer and it turned out it was an error in the text book that had been lifted straight into the mock exam.  He said they've been using this for years and no-one has noticed before.
So the good news is I wasn't going mad!

Answer (score 2):

The step under Rarrange is not correct.  The $0.35$ has become $30$

Comment: That’s exactly what I thought. I suppose it’s entirely possible that the text book has made a mistake, but the worrying thing is that we were given the question from a previous exam to help with our revision, and the answer given matches the book! I’ll ask my lecturer in the new year and will update this if I find anything else out about it